# Java Generics Hell - Passing in this but it wants type T

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently developing a lightweight, general-purpose simulation framework. The goal is to allow people to subclass the Simulation and Scenario objects for their domain-specific needs. Generics seemed like an appropriate way to achieve this, but I'm afraid I might be dipping into generics hell.

The `Sim` object provides access to the simulation entities and controls the sim (start/pause/stop)

The `Scenario` object allows you to populate the Sim with simulation entities.

Sim:

```
public class Sim 
{
  public <T extends Sim> void loadScenario(Scenario<T> scenario)
  {
      reset();
      scenario.load(this);
  }
}
```

Scenario:

```
public interface Scenario<T extends Sim>
{
    public void load(T sim);
}
```

The goal is to allow users to create a `MySim` that `extends Sim` and a `MyScenario` that `implements Scenario<MySim>` for their domain.

e.g. MyScenario:

```
public class MyScenario<MySim>
{
    public void load(MySim sim)
    {
        // make calls to sim.addMySimEntity(...)
    }
}
```

Specifically, using the code above, the `scenario.load(this)` call in `Sim.loadScenario` gives me the error: **The method load(T) in the type Scenario is not applicable for the arguments (Sim)**. I understand this is because I'm loading `this` (which is of type `Sim`) when what is required is `T extends Sim` which means somehow I should be passing in an object that can be *any subtype of Sim*.

What is the way to rectify this issue to achieve what I want to accomplish? Or, is it even possible? Perhaps generics can't do this for me.

Comment: I think this may be related to a question I asked about circular generic references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567595/creating-circular-generic-references

Answer (score 6):

If it is always going to be a subtype of Sim then why not just specify that in your method and be done with it?  It doesn't seem like generics is buying you very much here.

But anyway, I think you want `loadScenario` to be:

```
public void loadScenario(Scenario<? extends Sim> scenario)
```

**EDIT:** Okay now I actually thought about it, that won't work either.  Your loadScenario is going to get passed a Scenario with a type parameter T that is a subtype of Sim.  But you are trying to pass it a Sim which has no guarantees of being the right subtype of Sim.

The solution is that the Scenario.load method needs to take a Sim viz:

```
public interface Scenario<T extends Sim>
{
    public void load(Sim sim);
}
```

and Sim stays the way you wrote it.  Note your MySim class must implement this and explictily narrowcast it to it's type parameter.

**EDIT:** Another approach is to use a static method in your Sim base class:

```
public class Sim
{
    public static <T extends Sim> void loadScenario(Scenario<T> scenario, T sim)
    {
        scenario.load(sim);
    }
}
```

It is not however possible to make this an instance method since passing an instance of Sim to something of type T extends Sim is not typesafe.  By making a static method that also passes the Sim you give the compiler the opportunity to check that the T for Scenario type parameter and the T for sim match.

Comment: Surely you mean `load(T sim)` in the last case?  Else the generic parameter on the class is less than useful... :-)

Comment: @Andrzej No, I believe he meant load(Sim sim). Indeed, the generic on the class is no longer useful. It feels like I would not be able to accomplish what I'd like to do.

Comment: @Andrzej and @Brad. Correct, the generic is not that useful which was the point of the first part of the comment :-)  Normal polymorphism should be as effective here.

Comment: The question however still remains. Is it possible to use generics to accomplish this so I do not have to force a cast at run-time?

Comment: @Brad. You can't do it the way you have done.  It is possible as a static method. See Edit.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand this is because I'm
>   loading this (which is of type Sim)
>   when what is required is T extends Sim
>   which means somehow I should be
>   passing in an object that can be any
>   subtype of Sim.

No. The problem is that accoding to the method spec, you should be passing an object of class `T`, which is the specific *subclass* of `Sim` matching your scenario - which `this` is not (at least that code can't guarantee that it is).

Not sure how to fix this, though.