# cyclical generics definition A <B extends A<B>>

Tags: java, generics

I am reading javafx documentation, and didn't get what this definition means:

```
ObservableArray<T extends ObservableArray<T>>
```

I also read a very similar question about `SomeClass<T extends Comparable<T>>` ([Java- The meaning of <T extends Comparable<T>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537500/java-the-meaning-of-t-extends-comparablet)) but in this case I got the idea because it is not a cyclical definition. Also read this question [Cyclic generic dependenices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147308/cyclic-generic-dependenices) that is a kind of "two-step" cyclic generics, but I didn't get the meaning as well. What this pattern `A<B extends A<B>>` is supposed to mean?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think the easiest way to understand it is just that `T` here needs to be a type of ObservableArray.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Enum definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition)

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to refer to the current type with a type variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable)

Comment: None of the duplicates answer the question, and I would argue that there is no point for JavaFX's `ObservableArray`'s type parameter to have a recursive bound.