# Java generics - How do I read this: Foo<T extends Bar<? extends Foo<T>>>?

Tags: java, generics, crtp

I am bringing myself up to date with Java generics (having worked for a loooong time on legacy code with JDK 1.4... 1.3 even) and I don't quite understand this:

```
public class Foo<T extends Bar<? extends Foo<T>>> { ...
```

Where `Foo` and `Bar` are two generic classes.

How is this to be understood because I don't quite get it?

I've read a lot about Java generics but this is a little mind bending (at least for me as a beginner).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating circular generic references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567595/creating-circular-generic-references)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `Foo` has to be parameterized by a `T`. That `T` itself has to extend `Bar<U>` for some type `U` such that `U` extends `Foo<T>`. (Where "extend" can mean "is the same type as" in this case.) I've used `U` here as an arbitrary type name, but it's unnamed in the declaration, hence `?`.

You're right that it's a bit mind-bending, but typically in the circumstances where this sort of thing crops up, it ends up making things simpler. If you can give a concrete example, we may be able to explain a bit more usefully.