# How to get "circular" generics working in Java?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I am having an error while compiling the following code involving a few generics:

```
public abstract class State<T extends HasAState<? extends State<T>>>{
    protected T parent;

    public void setParent(){ // It's been simplified for the sake of the question!
        parent.removeState(this); // Error here!
        this.parent = parent;
        parent.addState(this);    // Error here!
    }
}

public interface HasAState<T extends State<? extends HasAState<T>>> {
    public void addState(T state);
    public void removeState(T state);
}
```

The errors are: `The method removeState(capture#1-of ? extends State<T>) in the type HasAState<capture#1-of ? extends State<T>> is not applicable for the arguments (State<T>)`

Actually what I would like to have is something like: `class A implements HasAState` and `class B extends State<A>` where `B` has a reference to `A` and can call `A.addState(B)` (only because `B` extends `State<A>`) and where `A` can call `B.setParent(this)`.

How should I declare my classes so that what I intend to do work?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should re-think your design... Are all these generics really necessary? Maybe there's a much more simple way to do what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567595/creating-circular-generic-references/2656027#2656027) is one way to create circular generic references in Java. If this is not what you are looking for, [browse similar threads](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[generics]+circular&submit=search).

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I get another error at the same location: `The method addState(E) in the type HasAState<P,E> is not applicable for the arguments (State<P,E>)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with the comment of Eran Zimmerman. It seams that you need to rethink about what you want.

Anyway I hope I have understand the problem right, so I changed the Parameter from one to tow, to describe the `state` and the `hasAState` separately.

```
public abstract class State<S extends State<S, H>, H extends HasAState<S, H>>{
    protected H parent;

    public void setParent(){ 
        parent.removeState(this);
        this.parent = parent; //!!!this line has no effect!!!
        parent.addState(this);        
    }       
}

public interface HasAState<S extends State<S, H>, H extends HasAState<S, H>> {
    public void addState(State<S, H> state);
    public void removeState(State<S, H> state);
}
```

This code compiles! -- be aware of the warning for the second line in `setParent`.

Answer (score 0):

My Analysis -

1. `A` has some state. ( beacuse `A implements HasState` )
2. `B` has    some state through `A` ( by containing a reference of `A` ) (
   because `B extends State<A>`)
3. The state in `A` above is essentially held in `B` ( because of `A.addState(B)` )  ( ? )

   This is a very convoluted design as it appears to me. Can you post what is your design essence without mentioning methods and parameters to them ?